# Contador caracteres tipo Twitter

Tags: java, java-swing, twitter

Deseo crear un contador tipo Twitter que vaya contando los caracteres de un JTextField y restándolos según se va escribiendo, y que cuando llegue a X cantidad, 250 por ejemplo, se ponga en rojo alertando al usuario (es para aun formulario) y no permita enviar el contenido a la siguiente ventana...

¿Alguno sabéis como hacerlo?

Espero haberme explicado bien :

Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 2):

Usando Java con JTextfield me parece que podrías seguir este modelo:

Tienes tu caja de texto JTextfield.

Añades al objeto, llamémoslo *myArea*, un listener que registra los cambios de tipo [DocumentEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html), tienes un ejemplo de esto [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

A partir de ahí, cada vez que se registra un cambio en la caja de texto *myArea*, podrías contar los caracteres obteniendo el texto de *myArea* y haciendo un String.length(), como en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789384/how-to-get-the-number-of-characters-in-a-jtextfield) pregunta.

Bastaría entonces con restar a tu número fijo (250) los caracteres actuales.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es añadir un listener al input e ir controlando la longitud del texto introducido y aplicar el estilo que desees dada una condición.
El listener se llamará cada vez que se modifique el texto de tu input.

[Ejemplo Listener para un JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/AddactionlistenertoJTextField.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Es algo muy común. Hay infinidad de ejemplos googleando, aquí uno:
https://www.taringa.net/comunidades/webdesign/8271687/Aporte-JavaScript-Contador-de-caracteres.html

Comment: Javascript no es java

Comment: La finalidad de mi comentario era indicar que podía buscar googleando lo que quisiera, que no necesita esperar aquí a que le demos la solución, que ya está cientos de veces.

Comment: @DavidLM he intentando encontrarlo en Google de una manera que entienda antes de preguntarlo por aquí, obviamente. Al no encontrar respuesta, he preguntado. ¿sabes como podría hacerlo en Java?